# What does "add()();" mean in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I'm getting different values for `i` by calling `add` function differently. Could someone explain what's happening here?

```
var i = 0;
var add = function() {
    ++i;
    return function() {
        i++;
        return function() {
            i++;
            add();
        }
    }
 };
add(); // i = 1;
add()(); // i = 2;        
add()()(); // i = 4;
```

​

Comment: Could you explain what you're trying to do?

Comment: In my test, add() returns `function () { i++; return function() { i++; add(); } }` instead of 1.

Comment: @JinzhaoWu: It's not about the return values.  It's about the value of `i` afterwards.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The function `add` returns a function. And this function returns another function.

So :

```
add(); // Executes add, which returns a function.
add()(); // Execute the function returned by add.
add()()(); // Execute the function returned by the function returned by add
```

Each function just adds 1 to the `i` value. That explains the `i` value.

Comment: Thank you for quick response. Makes sense now.

Answer (score 1):

Your `add` function returns a function.  So when you call this:

```
add();
```

what happens is the code (`++i`) executes and a function is returned.  You don't do anything with that function, but you *can*.  You can execute it:

```
add()();
```

This would run `++i`, return a function, run that function (which runs `i++`) and return another function (since that inner function also returns a function.

And so on.  Your functions are returning other functions, so any time you append another `()` to the call what you're doing is executing the function that's being returned.

Answer (score 1):

You are returning a function in add

By calling only

`add()`

The function is executed and i is increased by one // 1

When you call

`add()()`

The function that is returned by `add` gets executed too, and therefore increasing 
`i` by 2 // 2

`add()()()`

Invokes the funciton `add` returned, and the function the returned function returns,
which also calls `add` in it,
therefore increasing i by 4

But i thinl the code you are posted is slightly incorrect, the values should be

```
add() //i = 1
add()() // i = 3
add()()() //i = 7
```

Comment: Only the two-arg version seems to do an extra increment (by calling `add()`).  So at first glance, 1, 2, 4 looks like the right return values.  Why would they be otherwise?  ("Your code is incorrect, but it's returning the values you expect" isn't selling me here.)

Comment: `i` doesn't get resetted after the `add` is called -> i = 0 , + 1 = 1, +2 = 3, + 4 = 7;
I didn't actually test it, but I don't see an `i = 0` anywhere after the first call or in a function in the code

Answer (score 0):

Inside `add()` a new function is returned.

So calling `add()()` will execute `add()` first. After that the function returned by `add()` will be executed

Answer (score 0):

In javascript "()" is function invocation operator. So every time you call "()", it will try to invoke the function before this operator. In your case, a function is assigned to add. Let me assign each function a name so it will be very easy to understand.

```
var i = 0;
var add = function one() {
++i;
return function two() {
    i++;
    return function three() {
            i++;
            add();
        }
    }
};

// This will execute function one 
// and return function two.
add();   

// This will execute function one and two, 
// return function three
add()(); 

// This will execute function one, two, three,
// return function two. Why?
// Because in function three, we call add() which will execute
// function one and return function two as I mentioned above.
add()()();
```

Now let's see if you really understand function invocation.

```
var i = 0;
var add = function one() {
i++;
return function two() {
    i++;
    return function three() {
            i++;
        }
    }()
};
```

I delete the function add() inside function three in order to avoid infinity loop, and add "()" after function two.
So what if we call add() now?

```
// This will execute function one and return function two, 
// function two will invoke itself because of "()" at the end 
// I added and return function three. So call add() will 
// execute function one and function two, return function three.
// So i = 2 in this case.
add();
```

You can play around these function invocation all day long until you are confident with it.